# Linq to SQL - How to find the value of the IDENTITY column after InsertOnSubmit()

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, identity-column

I am using **LINQ to SQL** to insert simple data into a table WITHOUT a `stored procedure`.  The table has a Primary Key ID column, which is set as an `IDENTITY` column in both `SQL Server` and in my `DBML`.

First I call `InsertOnSubmit();` with data for a single row, and then I call `SubmitChanges();` to commit the row to the db.  But I think there must be a simple way to then retrieve the row's `IDENTITY` column value of the newly inserted row.  I don't wish to provide the `IDENTITY` column value to the db, I want it to generate one for me.

How is this best handled?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here is a simple code snippet

```
            Dim odb As New DataClassesDataContext
            Dim tst As New test
            tst.name = "abcd"
            odb.tests.InsertOnSubmit(tst)
            odb.SubmitChanges()
            Response.Write("id:" + tst.id.ToString)
```

so, basically the object you used in InsertOnSubmit will get the identity field populated after the record has been created in the database

Comment: Sooper, Thanks Vikram :)